# asp.net mvc BeginForm always action = "/"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc 4 and there is this weird problem:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form" }))
{   
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
}
```

the output:

```
<form action="/" class="login-form" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

and I am using these configurations in my web.config

```
<location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="assets">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="views">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: can you show complete view?

Comment: Login action in home controller must be ur default route ????

Comment: Please post your route configuration! Are you sure that any action/controller pair will be generated as `action="/"` because if your `Login` action on the `Home` is the default action in your route config it is normal to see  `action="/"` for that particular action.

Comment: yes my default action is Login thanks that help. but can you explain why this happening.

Comment: This happens because here Login action in home controller is ur default route in route.config file which is same as setting a page as start up page in asp.net so when ur app will first load login action of home controller will run that is why this ur form tag is showing action="/"..

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen, use this if problem does not resolve.....

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" class="login-form">
  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
</form>
```